# In r select only individuals (column "names") that has rows with yes and no in another column

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. The first column is for the observation date. The second is for the signaller ID. The third column is whether a chick was present during the observation (yes/no). How can I subset the dataframe to have all the rows with only those individuals that have observations with yes AND no?

For example, if I run

```
> table(presence.data$chick.present, presence.data$signaller.ID)
```

I get the following:

```
     ID. 1             ID. 2          ID. 3          ID. 4
no   48                 31             1              33   
yes  0                  0              0              2
```

So ideally, I would like to find a way to subset the data to have all rows of only the signaller "ID. 4" (currently the only one which was observed with "yes" AND "no" for chick presence.

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean something like this: `x <- as.data.frame(table(presence.data$chick.present, presence.data$signaller.ID))`  and `x[4]` ?

Comment: What you are trying to do is `subsetting` a `data.frame`.

Comment: You are looking for filter() with group_by()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` with `any()` for both conditions (chick.present==yes and chick.present==no)

```
library(dplyr)

presence.data %>% group_by(signaller.ID) %>% filter(any(chick.present=='yes') & any(chick.present=='no'))
```

Comment: Glad i could help. Please check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers